# How to make a dynamic javascript class.

Tags: javascript, jquery

another question! I am using Ajax to get the updated Billing Domain ID that is associated with the OfficeId Dropdown.

I have the need for an if statement that is changed dynamically. Here is what I am trying to accomplish. 
I want for certain fields to be hidden based on the BillingDomainID. For example, if BillingDomainID is 1, I want to hide the fields. The trick is that I want to be able to expand as time goes on so that it can also be used for other IDs as they arise.

Here is what I have so far without any success.

```
    function getOfficeInfo(OID, BDID) { 
    //alert(OID); 
    //alert(BDID); 
    $.post("/UserControls/getOfficeInfo.asp", {OfficeID: OID}, function(data) {
        BDID.val(data); 

        var vBDID
        vBDID = ".BillingDomainID" + data;
        //alert(vBDID);

        if (data != 1) {
            $(vBDID).hide();
        }
    }); 
    //alert(data);
}
```

I am just needing to know how to make the $(vBDID).hide(); part work.

Comment: What "without any success" means?

Comment: Are you saying you want to dynamically hide fields based on `BillingDomainId`? If so, do you have control over the HTML?

Comment: Can you include an example `data` variable that is returned by $.post? Is it just a number, or an object?

Comment: does the element with class = ".BillingDomainID" + data exists in the DOM ?

Comment: @TennysonH, it is simply a number 1-8.

Comment: @PavelGatnar, That is what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @DinoMyte, The class is listed throughout the html with an example as follows:
 <tr class=" BillingDomainID1">... </tr>

Comment: @PavelGatnar, but would that not allow for it to only be assigned to a single field that I want to hide, as to where a class would allow for it to be on many fields, which is what I want.

Comment: @RobM. That is exactly right! That is what I am wanting. I do have control over HTML

Comment: @KyleLoganWray: The example you posted has a space in the class attribute. Is that is how it is or it was done in error ?

Comment: @DinoMyte, If you mean the example in the reply to you, it may just be in error when I was trying to shorten the code. It is correct in the file. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your element isn't hiding unless your typing your class name incorrectly. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hqzf39jr/) that shows how this works.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="someClass" type="button">
Hi there
</button>






$(function(){

    var thing = '.someClass';

  $('button').on('click', function(){
        $(thing).hide(); 
  })
});
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, but it is not what I am trying to accomplish, I I need something that can have a number (BillingDomainID) appended to the end of the class so that it can change based on which billingdomainID is selected.

Comment: Not according to your question: "I am just needing to know how to make the $(vBDID).hide(); part work." This answers it perfectly. It's what you asked...

Comment: Okay, please forgive me.
I am however still needing to understand how to do the appended number at the end like:
    var vBDID
        vBDID = ".BillingDomainID" + data;
        if (data != 1) {
            $(vBDID).hide();
        }
Do you happen to know how to make this part work? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: It appears to me that part should be working just fine.

Comment: Okay, we maybe my inexperience is not helping, but do you see any part of my code above that looks off somehow?

Comment: `if (data != 1)` this says that if the data is not equal to 1, the element will hide. But it sounds like you want to hide ONLY if the data IS equal to 1 `if (data == 1)`

Comment: Thank you for that input. I will be using this statement for several different situations, so I will be sure to change to the == for those that it is applicable. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Sure thing. Since I answered your original question, could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to go about this, since you have control over the HTML I think you have two direct approaches:

**Create a map of fields to Billing Domains Ids**

```
var fieldMap = {
  '1': ['first-name', 'last-name', ...],
  '2': ['first-name', 'last-name', 'ssn', ...],
  ...
};
```

Then you can do something like (assuming `data` is the billing domain id:

```
var $form = $('form');
// hide everything by default
$form.find('input').hide();
// show all fields that pertain to this domain
$form.find(fieldMap[data].map(function(field) {
  // gives you '[name="first-name"]'), etc.
  return '[name="'+field+'"]';
})).show();
```

**Add class names to inputs to indicate which billing domain ids they are shown for**

```
<input type="text" name="first-name" class="domain-1 domain-2 domain-3" />
```

And then:

```
$form.find('.domain-'+data).show();
```

Though I feel like that could get kind of messy if you have a lot of domains.